# Jquery.ajax sends null to controller, but works with hard-coded variables

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I was making a simple app in vs code, and I want to save values into database, this is what I have so far.

```
 var naziv = $("#TextNaziv").val();
        var cena = $("#TextCena").val();
        var opis = $("#TextOpis").val();

        //console.log("Cena:" + cena);
       // console.log("Opis:" + opis);
       // console.log("Naziv:" + naziv);

        var proizvod = {
            Naziv: "nazivTest123",
            Cena: 33,
            Opis: "opisTest123"
        }

       // console.log(proizvod);
        var zahtev = $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Home/UbaciProizvod",
            data: JSON.stringify(proizvod),
            contentType: "application/json",
            dataType: "text",

        });
```

And this works just fine without any problems, but when I change the var proizvod to:

```
var proizvod = {
     Naziv: naziv,
     Cena: cena,
     Opis: opis
        }
```

The app just won't save the values into the db, even tho I checked in console and the values are just fine, the controller receives null value. I tried everything I saw on the internet but nothing seems to help, maybe is some minor issue but I cannot solve it, my controller function looks like this:

```
public int UbaciProizvod([FromBody] Proizvod p )
{
    string upit = @"INSERT INTO Proizvod VALUES(@Naziv,@Cena,@Opis);
                            SELECT CAST(SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS int)";

        using(SqlConnection konekcija = new SqlConnection(Konekcija.CnnMagacin))
        {
            try
            {
                int id = konekcija.QuerySingleOrDefault<int>(upit,p);
                return id;

            }
            catch (System.Exception)
            {
                
               return -1;
            }
        }
}
```

This is my first post so every suggestion and critics are welcomed, and sorry about the variable names.

Comment: I would suggest you debug the response coming back from the request. That being said, the only difference I can see is that `val()` returns a string yet in the working hard-coded version you give the `Cena` an integer value. As such you may need to convert to an integer: `Cena: parseInt(cena, 10)`

Comment: Works like a charm, thank you my brother!, I used 'Cena: parseInt(cena, 10)' just like you suggested and it solved everything. Thank you once again

Comment: Glad it helped. I added it as an answer for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference between the two versions is that you provide `Cena` as an integer value in the working version, but a string in the non-working one.

To fix this call `parseInt()` on the value before making the AJAX request:

```
var proizvod = {
  Naziv: naziv,
  Cena: parseInt(cena, 10),
  Opis: opis
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering, but I do have to ask you more now that you mentioned SQL injection, I know what it is but are you sure that code above is open for SQL injection, because I found the exact same method for inserting values on the https://dapper-tutorial.net, and I've seen some tutorials too using dapper like this, there are parameters in sql query, and as far as I know Dapper being an ORM maps entity properties with the matching SQL columns.

Comment: You're right - your usage of Dapper is correct. In fact I missed you were using Dapper at all and misread your code. My mistake.